# Chrome rendering issues - White spots on popup background overlay

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, user-interface, rendering

Recently few users informed that google chrome shows strange white spots on the UI. As a developer I can't regenerate on any of computers windows, Mac. All the users complained this UI issues use Windows Chrome. When I scroll or change the window size these white spots disappear and appear again in different locations. Highly appreciate if someone can give me a clue of solving this problem.

I am using bootbox to show the popup.

```
addDialog = bootbox.dialog({
      message: addPopupHTML,
      title: "Add New Employee / Worker"
    })
```

`addPopupHTML` is the HTML of the form.

[image]

Comment: @JaromandaX Really appreciate if you can provide any reference. I have no clue what line 37 is. Thank you.

Comment: My fault I thought you are helping me. I know it's my code that's why asked for a clue for a fix.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with the code segment with bootbox.

Comment: so, it only occurs when there's a `bootbox.dialog` visible? the contents of which are `addPopupHTML` (I assume that var holds very basic HTML only) -

Comment: Yes just basic HTML forms. and this issue started to happen recently with no code changes

Comment: does showing a `bootbox.dialog` add an element that overlays the underlying page? with  blur maybe? And you say you can't duplicate the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem. It seems to be an issue with a graphic card driver as my customers all experienced the bug after a driver update from windows.

The problem is with the backdrop overlay. If you hide the .modal-backdrop.fade.in, the spots disappear too.

Our quick and dirty solution for an intermediat fix was, to add this to the stylesheet:

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

This will lead to some sort of weird flash on closing the modal but at least it helps removing the white spots

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to chrome version 62. I had a same problem while displaying modal background with jQuery animation. And now the issue is solved by upgrading my chrome browser.